# What is the recommended approach for logging Spring Security OAuth2 authentication failures?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on a Spring web application (not Spring Boot) that uses Spring Security 5.3.3, Spring Security OAuth 2.5.0, and configures it like this:

```
http.authorizeRequests().
    antMatchers(permitUrls).
    permitAll().
    anyRequest().
    authenticated().
    and().
    oauth2ResourceServer().
    jwt();
```

Our clients report occasional 401 responses which we can't find in our application logs, so we assume it's from the Spring Security itself. We would like to log authentication and authorization failures, but I'm confused as to what is the current preferred method to achieve that.

A quick search reveals 4 paths:

- custom AuthenticationFailureHandler (seems like this one is only available in FormLoginConfigurer, which isn't our case)
- custom AuthenticationEntryPoint (this one is available with JWT, but OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint which I was going to extend is [deprecated with an unhelpful message](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/error/OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint.java)). I could try using HttpStatusEntryPoint instead, but I'd like to avoid changing the current behavior of my app, just want to add logging.
- custom Filter (probably, not the cleanest path)
- [AuditApplicationEvents](https://blog.mafr.de/2017/04/18/spring-boot-logging-failed-logins/) — looks beautiful, but seems like it's for Spring Boot only.

Could anyone provide me with some guidance on this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest activating the logger of `org.springframework.security` by changing its log level to DEBUG.
Based on your log tools (log4j2, logback, ...) create a logger in your log configurations with name `org.springframework.security` and level `DEBUG`.